# How to disable / cancel undo button in xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, keyboard

I am creating an application that has an entry. I am trying to restrict the entry to only allow for numeric input. I have already tried using Keyboard = "Numeric". For the iPad, however, the keyboard has more characters than just numbers. So I had to restrict what is entered. When I do this however, if the user types in a parenthesis, for example, it does stop the character from being entered. But then if the user presses undo, it crashes. I assume this is because the software keyboard is separate from the app, so it is looking for that parenthesis character, but it isn't there. Here is my code:

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Entry theEntry = (Entry)sender;
        string entryText = theEntry.Text;
        if(entryText != null && entryText.Length != 0)
        {
            char theMostRecentInput = entryText[entryText.Length - 1];
            if(!Extension.IsNumeric(theMostRecentInput))
            {
                theEntry.TextChanged -= Entry_TextChanged;
                theEntry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
                theEntry.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure how to fix this, but you have another mistake. You're assuming that the most recently typed character is the last character in the string. A better way to go about this would probably be to validate the number when the user completes the form and inform the user if the string contains invalid characters. Setting the string in a textbox that the user is typing in will cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

This issue will occur when Validation like special character, Max Limit, etc... for Input field are implemented. 
By that time undo action will have extra character count than current input field text characters length in iOS ShouldChangeCharacters Delegate. This leads to app crash.
One of the solution  is to return as false in such scenario instead of disabling undo buttons. Below solution worked for me.

```
public class ExtEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
            Control.ShouldChangeCharacters += (UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString) =>
                {
                if (range.Location + range.Length > ((UITextField)textField).Text.Length)
                        return false;
                    return true;
                };
            }                          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a `Entry` custom renderer that way you you can control the input via `ShouldChangeCharacters` and not have to kludge it by allowing the input and then having to remove the handler and change the text back to the old value...

Here is a quick example that allows numeric, It also automatically handles clipboard pasting non-numeric strings as those would be disallowed. I am using the `NSCharacterSet.DecimalDigits` character set as that would be internationalized by the OS, but you could allow/disallow any chars of your choosing.

You could also include haptic, visual or audio feedback on the disallowed/rejected entries...

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NumericEntry), typeof(NumericEntryRenderer))]
namespace Forms_PCL_Tester.iOS
{
    public class NumericEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != e.OldElement)
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation;
                    Control.ShouldChangeCharacters += (UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString) =>
                     {
                         foreach (var aChar in replacementString)
                             if (!NSCharacterSet.DecimalDigits.Contains(aChar))
                                 return false;
                         return true;
                     };
                }
        }
    }
}
```